# sqlserver index on numeric fields for zero non zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table with a numeric field like this:

```
table invoices (
  inv_number       varchar(20), 
  amount           numeric(13,2), 
  amount_remaining numeric(13,2) )
```

and I often have to query this table to extract records with zero values or non zero values.

```
select invnumber from invoices  
where amount_remaining=0  
... or  ...
where amount_remaining!=0
```

I know the best soulution would be to add a precalculated boolean field,

**but I can't touch the table structure** (can't add fields).

I can only work on indexes or views.

Is it a good idea to add an index on this numeric field just to filter for zero / non-zero values?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i know the best soulution would be to add a precalculated boolean field

Not at all. That would help nothing.

```
select invnumber from invoices  
where amount_remaining=0  
... or  ...
where amount_remaining!=0
```

This query is non-sargable. Any possible optimization would depend entirely on what else in in the WHERE clause. Unless a sargable expression exists there the query requires a full scan so there cannot be any discussion about optimizing it.

> is it a good idea to add an index on this numeric field just to filter for zero non-zero values?

No. You also have the condition `where amount_remaining=0 ...` so the index would not help.

Ultimately you have  non-sensical condition. You want records that satisfy a predicate or the negated predicate. That will always be, by definition, everything (not considering three valued NULL logic). You ask whether a filtered index would help. A filtered index would help one of the two parts of your WHERE clause, but never both.

```
select invnumber from invoices  
where amount_remaining=0 and ...;
```

this would be helped by a filtered index with a `amount_remaining=0` *if the percentage of records where `ammount_remaning=0` is small*.

**or**

```
select invnumber from invoices  
where amount_remaining!=0 and ...;
```

this would be helped by a filtered index with a `amount_remaining!=0` *if the percentage of records where `ammount_remaning!=0` is small*.

Obviously you can't have *both* criteria be a 'small percent' at once.

If you look for a good index you'll have to search in some other parts of the WHERE clause, some parts that do not express, simulatenously, a predicate and its negation OR-ed together.

Comment: Of course i wont use both the condizions in the same query (equals or not equals).Let's say i have 50% of record equals to zero, my goal is to get a faster access to one half or the other per time, eg: for count() or sum().

Comment: Read about [Index Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/) to learn why no index can help '50%', unless is [covering](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/). You may give a try to create *two* covering indexes, one filtered for `=0` and one for `!=0` and see if they get picked up. If they're narrow it should improve the scan time (they still require a full NC index scan). They must be covering, the sum/count query should be *simple*.

Comment: It's not quite non-sargable in that the optimizer knows just where to seek: the first zero value. From that point on, however, it must perform a range scan. There is really no way around it. The query is asking for all rows with zero values (or not-zero values) and all those rows must be visited, whether that is 5 rows or 5mm rows. Additional filtering criteria can narrow that range considerably, but if the only criteria is the value of one field, the scan must be performed. There is no trick you can perform to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

index is not used for filter, yes view will use for this. You can create a view with as your condition which filter the data.

Index is used for fast searching, the same as we use index in a book.

**Update**
Yes you can give non-clustered index on above column which give faster result.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Tablename_ColumnName 
    ON Databasename.Tablename (columnname);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189280.aspx

Comment: thaks for answer but it was not exaclty what i was looking for, maybe my "filter" term was confusing. I need to optimize a query on that filed not just filtering it ...